# LDAP Authentication fails with 500 or 401 depending on bind for Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, svn, ldap, redhat

I'm setting up LDAP authentication for our Subversion repository hosted through Apache on a RHEL 5 system. I run into two different issues when I try to authenticate against Active Directory.

```
<Location /svn/>
Dav svn
SvnParentPath /srv/subversion
SVNListParentPath On
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repository"

AuthBasicProvider ldap

AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=userfoo,ou=Service Accounts,ou=User Accounts,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "mypass"

AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://my.example.com:389/ou=User Accounts,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)" NONE

Require valid-user
</Location>
```

If I use the above configuration it continually prompts me with the Basic prompt and I have to eventually select Cancel, which returns a 401 (Authorization Required). If I comment out the bind parts it returns 500 (Internal Server Error), griping that authentication failed:

```
[Mon Nov 02 12:00:00 2009] [warn] [client x.x.x.x] [10744] auth_ldap authenticate: user myuser authentication failed; URI /svn [ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed][Operations error]
```

When I perform the bind using ldapsearch and filter for a simple attribute it returns correctly:

```
ldapsearch -h my.example.com -p 389 -D "cn=userfoo,ou=Service Accounts,ou=User Accounts,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com" -b "ou=User Accounts,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com" -w - "&(objectClass=user)(cn=myuser)" sAMAccountName
```

Unfortunately I have no control or insight into the AD part of the system, only the RHEL server. Does anyone know what the hang up is here?

Comment: What does apache error_log say?

Comment: It's the code block just after the _griping that authentication failed:_ statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was nearly there. I simply missed the `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off` directive which is specific to my instance.

As a further note we also wanted to limit the repo to only identified users so we chained the authentication with a file as well. Example below:

```
RedirectMatch ^(/repos)$ $1/
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /repos/>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/svn/repos
    SVNListParentPath On
    SVNAutoversioning On

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"

    AuthBasicProvider file ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPBindDN "OU=Service Accounts,OU=User Accounts,DC=example,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xXxXxXx
    AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://ldap.example.com:389/OU=User Accounts,DC=example,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)"

    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn-authn
    SVNIndexXSLT "/styles/svnindexICore.xsl"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-file 

    #AuthBasicProvider file ldap
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The identical configuration i tested on Ubuntu did not work on RHEL5.
I ended up changing from port 389 to 3268 [after reading this](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=383760) and that fixed my problem.

Comment: Hi Kieren, can you please include some of the salient details of that discussion (like what specific steps you took to resolve the problem) in your answer? This makes your answer useful if that form post ever goes away ([see here for more info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259))

Answer (score 1):

Comparing your configuration to a working configuration with Active Directory on Apache 2.2.3 the only differences I'm seeing are:

- I am using the "DOMAIN\sAMAccountName" style username for my `AuthLDAPBindDN`
- I do not have `NONE` after my `AuthLDAPURL`

Aside from those suggestions, I'd recommend running `tcpdump` on the conversation between Apache and Active Directory to see what might be transpiring there, too.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about LDAP as I have used SSPI auth for my setup. But I found these pages with nice details on LDAP configuration. (Just in case you havent yet gotten to them):

http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/03/subversion-with-apache-and-ldap-updated.html

http://www.novell.com/communities/node/5679/installing-and-configuring-subversion-server-and-apache2-ldap-authentication-against-edire

The apache version seems to make a difference to the syntax.

Also the order in which the LDAP modules are loaded.

Comment: I found these docs as well. unfortunately they didn't provide any insight as to the underlying issue

Answer (score 0):

Your LDAPUrl makes apache create query: `&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=myuser)`

And your command line query is: `&(objectClass=user)(cn=myuser)`

Which one is correct? If you say your command line test works ok, then you probably need:

`AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://my.example.com:389/ou=User Accounts,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com?cn?sub?(objectClass=user)" NONE`

Comment: cn or SAMAccountName are both available, and in the case of our network interchangeable.

Comment: Can you access the AD logs? It would be good to confront what apache asks the AD.

I have similar configuartion with OpenLDAP and it is working fine. So a problem musy lay somewhere else. Maybe some SE extensions or sth? Maybe apache process is not able to open sockets? No other ideas.

Comment: I spoke with the LDAP admin and they couldn't identify anything in the logs. Also problematic is the LDAP instance deals with logins from nearly 13,000 accounts daily. A proverbial needle.

Comment: Couldn't identify anything? This seems strange :) At least he should be able to tell you if the apach at least connects, and later what queries it issues.