# Apache Subversion with active directory authentication not working

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, svn

I'm trying to configure Apache Subversion with active directory but the credentials of a domain user are not working. I'm new to Subversion but what I had first was:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authorization Realm"
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-users
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

This worked using the credentials created with htpasswd.

I have now edited the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` file like this:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authorization Realm"
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://server.example.local/dc=example,dc=local?sAMAccountName" NONE
   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "<password>"
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

When I check the /var/log/httpd/access_log I don't see errors, just this:

```
192.168.1.3 - user1 [26/Aug/2015:07:45:05 +0200] "GET /svn/project_repo HTTP/1.1" 401 479 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.12) Gecko/20130104 Firefox/10.0.12"
```

When I check the /var/log/httpd/error_log, I see there is a password mismatch:

```
[Wed Aug 26 08:05:22 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] user user1: authentication failure for "/svn/project_repo": Password Mismatch
```

But I am sure the password is right.

Are there other logs I can check? Or is my configuration just wrong?

**EDIT:**
Apparently the DN was wrong, I ran the `dsquery user > c:\dn.txt` on the AD server to get the right DN. When I try to login now, I get an Internal Server Error, but there are no errors in the `/var/log/httpd/error_log` file. Any other files I can check?

Comment: Did you reload / restart your Apache to activate the changes? Would be the most trivial explanation ...

Comment: Yes, I executed `service httpd restart` but I still get the same result

Comment: ok. Than you should double check your dn config. [reading this servervault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/111603/why-wont-my-apache-ldap-authentication-work-password-mismatch) your error message might be caused by wrong dn.

Comment: The DN was wrong indeed. I ran the `dsquery user > c:\dn.txt` command on AD and I got the following DN for the administrator user: `AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=MPMV,DC=LOCAL"` I now get an Internal Server Error but I don't see anything in the error_log..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/80762/ldap-authentication-fails-with-500-or-401-depending-on-bind-for-apache2) saying you should change the port number to 3268. It is working now! My `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` file looks like this now:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authorization Realm"
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server.example.LOCAL:3268/dc=example,dc=local?sAMAccountName" NONE
   AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "PASSWORD"
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```